# Sequelize in NodeJS : Inner JOIN implementation Failure

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, orm, sequelize.js

I have three tables contractors, projects and jointable for these two is projects_contractors and i created models and wrote a relation like below,

```
    Contractor.hasMany(Project, {joinTableName: 'projects_contractors'})
    Project.hasMany(Contractor, {joinTableName: 'projects_contractors'})
```

I want to access this Contractor based projects means inner JOIN.

Core query : 
                 select c.id,c.name,p.id,p.name from contractors c inner join projects_contractors pc on c.id=pc.contractor_id inner join projects p  on p.id = pc.project_id

I was failed in implementing the below code. "required" is a keyword which used for inner JOIN but not working if we keep.

```
     Contractor.findAll({ include: [Project, {required: false}]}).success(function(list){
       console.log("hi")
         res.send(204)
     })
```

If not keeping required it will creates a left outer JOIN on projects and contractors.  Suggest me with a sample example for the above senario.

Comment: Have you tried `required: true`?

Comment: @MickHansen : Yes, I tried, but showing below error:                                                    Include malformed. Expected attributes: daoFactory, as!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

`Contractor.findAll({ include: [{model: Project, required: true}]})`

Generally the include params take either a model, or an object with a model parameter and optional as/required/include/where params.